# In C, how do I concatenate parts of different longs?

Tags: c, long-integer

Given a random array of unsigned long bits, for example:

```
bits = { 0xABCDEF001234567A, 0x98761111FCDFEC80 };
```

How do I write the method `unsigned long getbits(unsigned long bits[], unsigned idx, unsigned len)` that returns the bits from `idx` to `idx + len - 1`?

For the example, `getbits(bits, 56, 20)` returns `0x0000000000067A98`.

Comment: Is there a maximum length? And how does it relate to the builtin types?

Comment: Use bit shifting and masking. You'll also need to divide the index by the size in bits of `unsigned long` to get the starting array index.

Comment: @Deduplicator 16, yes.

Comment: hm, 20 is more than 16, so what do you mean with 16?

Comment: There's a very useful [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page from Stanford. I don't know if it has exactly what you're looking for, but you can certainly learn some interesting techniques.

Comment: Your question is bit confusing be specific on what you need with the getbits function

Comment: Note that the hard things are: 1) you don't want to access past the end of the array, so you can't always access two consecutive words 2) you can't shift 64 bits, only 0-63 are allowed. With these two things in mind you can construct the function using bit operations.

Comment: @Deduplicator 98761111FCDFEC80 has 16 characters.

Comment: `bits` or `bytes`? What do you expect when `len` is not divisible by 4, e.g. `getbits(bits, 0, 3)` ? technically, you could write out the binary representation to a string and get what you want with string methods.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `long` is 64-bit, and assuming `len` is no larger than 64, you can do the following:

First divide `idx` by 64 to get the array index, then mod by 64 to get the starting bit number.

Start by taking the array element in question and shifting left by the bit index, then right by the bit index.  This will shift off the extra bits on the left and shift 0's back on.

Now subtract the bit index and the length from 64.  This gives you the number of bits to strip off on the right side.  If the result is non-negative, shift right by that value and you're done.  If the result is negative, then you need to get the rest from the next element in the array.  Start by shifting your result value left by the negation of is value to make room for the additional bits.  Then grab the next array element and right shift it by 64 + the negative value, then perform a bitwise OR of this value and your final result.

The resulting function:

```
unsigned long getbits(unsigned long arr[], int idx, int len)
{
    int bitlen = sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT;
    if (len > bitlen) {
        printf("len too long\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int arridx = idx / bitlen;
    int bitidx = idx % bitlen ;
    int rightshift = bitlen - bitidx - len;

    unsigned long r = (arr[arridx] << bitidx) >> bitidx;
    if (rightshift >= 0) {
        r = r >> rightshift;
    } else {
        r = r << -rightshift;
        r = r | (arr[arridx + 1] >> (bitlen + rightshift));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Should be `sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: @DietrichEpp Good catch.  Fixed.